# Woocommerce Product page layout not proper

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the latest woocommerce plugin on my site. I used enfold theme for my site. but I don't know why my product page structure broken or not displayed properly like other.

1. Product gallery thumb is not working (all images are displayed in 100% width, no carousel for product images)
2. I am not able to set sidebar

is this problem with enfold theme or anything else?

Comment: Can you please include your `woocommerce/single.php` code or at least include link to your website?

Comment: It's an issue between Enfold and WooCommerce 3.0. You'll probably find you can solve it by selecting in the theme settings: Shop Options > Product Gallery > WooCommerce 3.0 Product Gallery. There's loads of threads about it in the Kriesi forums

Answer (score 0):

Your theme does not support the latest Woocommerce version (3.1.1), see screenshot.

[image]

Either install an old version of Woocommerce (3.0.x) or latest from [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/releases) or wait for your theme next update.

You can also update your theme files yourself but that would be a waste of time since you do not have to.

Comment: i tried with these two versions woocommerce 3.0.9 and  2.7.0. but no luck.

Comment: share a link to your page

Comment: sorry but it is on localhost

Comment: Share HTML then

Comment: you are removing the new version then installing the new one, right?

Comment: yeah i removed  3.1.1 and installed 3.0.9. still i am not getting the perfect product page like others.

Comment: Of course, you will not get the same page style, because it is usually affected by used theme, the question is: is it working or not? if it is not, then let us discuss how to fix it, else, check your theme settings for Woocommerce options, if you do not have then the effect that your theme has over default Woocommerce behaviour does not suit you and you will have to update it manually, get what changes you want to do, then post your questions on how to do it